# Java datastructure for a list of type and collection of type

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a collection where each node is either Class A or a collection of Class A.

This is also recursive in that each node in the collection of Class A could be Class A or a collection of Class A.

I am currently just using List and then checking the Object to see if it is Class A or a List of Class A but that seems to defeat the purpose of using generics. I think I need a more tree like structure. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating a class (`Wrapper<ClassA>`) that can hold either an instance of `ClassA` or a `List`. Then make your `Lists` and inner `Lists` be `List<Wrapper<ClassA>>`

Comment: If you can implement the Composite design patters as mishadoff suggests, that would be even better but it may not be possible as operations may not be possible against a list of the elements.

Comment: yeah in my case I just need to get the object, not perform an operation against it. Still all the suggestions match what I was thinking so that is a good sign!

Comment: FYI, FunctionalJava has an Either class that might be usefull: http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/data/Either.html

Answer (score 5):

Look at the [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) design pattern.

Comment: This is also a good response but just happened to not match my current needs.

Answer (score 2):

When you instantiate a generic type you're still going to have homogeneous types stored in the collection. The way that you do this, in the real world, is to establish a common medium, a container, or an interface that binds class A and B together. You use the interface to manipulate those objects.

Alternatively, you can treat objects, by default, as a list. See what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

You should Define class Node Like below

```
    public class Node {
       List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }
```